# script not waiting for ajax return?

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have this long function in jquery that includes a jquery ajax call, some css changes, and repositioning the div. Here is my code:

```
$('.editable').click(function(e) {
    //assign the attributes for the ajax call                         
    $('#employeelist span').html("job: " + $(this).attr("editjob") + "<br />date: " + $(this).attr("editdate").substr(5));
    $('#employeelist').attr("editjob", $(this).attr("editjob"));
    $('#employeelist').attr("editdate", $(this).attr("editdate"));  
    //update the employee list with AJAX
    $.get("getDaySchedule.php", 
        {'job': $('#employeelist').attr("editjob"), 'date': $('#employeelist').attr("editdate")},
        function(responsetext){$('#employeelist ul').html(responsetext);},
        "html"
    );
    //show the employee list
    $('#employeelist').show()
    .css('top',$(this).offset().top+25)
    .css('left',($(this).offset().left+130))
    .css('visibility', "visible")
    .removeClass()
    .addClass($(this).attr('class'));
    //adjust the employee list if it goes outside the viewable area:
    if ($('#employeelist').height() + $('#employeelist').offset().top > $(window).height()) {
        newtop = ($('#employeelist').height() + $('#employeelist').offset().top) - $(window).height();
        newtop = $('#employeelist').offset().top - newtop;
        $('#employeelist').css('top',newtop);
    };
    if ($('#employeelist').width() + $('#employeelist').offset().left > $(window).width()) {
        newleft = $('#employeelist').offset().left - 260;
        $('#employeelist').css('left',newleft);
    };
});
```

The problem I'm having is that it appears the last section of code (where it repositions the div if it is outside the viewable area) is being run BEFORE the ajax call is done. So basically the height of the div is very short because it hasn't gotten the response text yet. This results in the div being too tall and going past the viewable area, because it isn't being repositioned off the correct height. Hopefully that makes sense. Is there something I'm missing in the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax by default is asynchronous, meaning that once it is called the following code will run without waiting for the ajax call to return; therefore, it is not complete when your following code runs. You need to move your code within the success of the ajax.

```
$('.editable').click(function(e) {
    var $editable = $(this);
    var $employeeList = $('#employeelist');

    //assign the attributes for the ajax call                         
    $('#employeelist span').html("job: " + $editable.attr("editjob") + "<br />date: " + $editable.attr("editdate").substr(5));
    $employeeList.attr("editjob", $editable.attr("editjob"));
    $employeeList.attr("editdate", $editable.attr("editdate"));  

    //update the employee list with AJAX
    $.get("getDaySchedule.php", 
        {'job': $employeeList.attr("editjob"), 'date': $employeeList.attr("editdate")},
        function(responsetext){
            $('#employeelist ul').html(responsetext);

            //show the employee list
            $employeeList.show()
                .css('top', $editable.offset().top+25)
                .css('left', ($editable.offset().left+130))
                .css('visibility', "visible")
                .removeClass()
                .addClass($editable.attr('class'));

            //adjust the employee list if it goes outside the viewable area:
            if ($employeeList.height() + $employeeList.offset().top > $(window).height()) {
                newtop = ($employeeList.height() + $employeeList.offset().top) - $(window).height();
                newtop = $employeeList.offset().top - newtop;
                $employeeList.css('top',newtop);
            }

            if ($employeeList.width() + $employeeList.offset().left > $(window).width()) {
                newleft = $employeeList.offset().left - 260;
                $employeeList.css('left',newleft);
            }
        }
    );    
});
```

**Edit**:

I have updated the code to fix the issue you were having. Note I also cached the most commonly used jquery selectors. It is always a good idea to cache the selectors that you more than once to improve the performance of your code.

Comment: Ohh thanks for showing me firebug, this is so useful! Can't believe I haven't been using this. Yes actually, firebug alerted me that $(this).offset() is null, which I was trying to have the #employeelist repositioned based on which .editable item was clicked. And I guess now that these functions are inside the ajax callback function, it no longer recognizes $(this)... any ideas on how to update this?

Comment: Ah nevermind I figured it out, it was just an issue of scope as $(this) refers to something else inside the ajax callback function. I had to store the original $(this) into it's own variable that I can then reference in the callback function.... thanks for the help!

Comment: You might still want to check out the end of my answer and the recommendations I made.

Comment: Yea thanks for the tip, I've implemented your suggestions. I noticed you left out the "html" declaring the datatype from the .get function. I know this is optional, but it seems like you would want to declare it if you do know the datatype to expect. Any reasoning on this?

Comment: There wasnt any particular reason other than it not being required. It is all a matter of preference whether you want to keep it or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your repositioning code inside the AJAX callback function, so where you have:

```
 function(responsetext){$('#employeelist ul').html(responsetext);}
```

Inside that function you need to do all your repositioning.